# How to get all the tags with same name inside an XML file using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, tags

The XML that I am using is of this format -

```
<head>
  <body>
  Sample Text1
  </body>
  <body>
  Sample Text2
  </body>
</head>
```

I am trying to get all the tags with tag `<body>` into a single variable `final_value`. For that, I am using the code below -

```
soup = Soup(target_xml, 'html.parser') 
for value in soup.find_all("body"):
    final_value = value.prettify()
```

Using this, I am getting only one `<body>` tag inside the `final_value` variable. How can I get both the tags inside the variable so that the output would be like this -

```
>> final_value
      <body>
      Sample Text1
      </body>
      <body>
      Sample Text2
      </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


target_xml = """<head>
  <body>
  Sample Text1
  </body>
  <body>
  Sample Text2
  </body>
</head>"""

final_value = ""
soup = BeautifulSoup(target_xml, 'html.parser') 
for value in soup.find_all("body"):
    final_value += value.prettify()

print(final_value)
```

**Output:**

```
<body>
 Sample Text1
</body>
<body>
 Sample Text2
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, I am using this for loop in another for loop. So, everytime the outer loop gets executed, previous value of final_value variable is appended to new value.

Comment: Yes, flushing the variable after every loop solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially overwriting the first `value` with the second one in these lines:

```
for value in soup.find_all("body"):
    final_value = value.prettify()
```

Instead try something like this:

```
for value in soup.find_all("body"):
        final_value += value.prettify()
```

Comment: Actually, I am using this for loop in another for loop. So, everytime the outer loop gets executed, previous value of final_value variable is appended to new value.

Comment: But flushing the variable after every loop solved the problem. Thanks :)